# How To implement Day/Night for a PDF File in Windows Store App?

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I am trying to implement Day/Night mode for a pdf file; after rendering.
What is the best possible solution to do this? Can it be done by using Themes In Windows Store?

Comment: What are you using to create the PDF file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Venkata also [posted on the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/2909fc75-f519-4d6f-a968-3ca350c9e6be/how-to-implement-daynight-mode-for-pdfrendering-in-windows-store?forum=winappswithcsharp), where he clarified that he's using the PdfDocument API and wants to invert white for black and black for white. If you do this, make sure you take High Contrast modes into account (I'd just skip your inversion in high contrast mode since the user is managing that already).

You can set the page background in the PdfPageRenderOptions you pass to RenderToStreamAsync (or the PDF_RENDER_PARAMS if you're using IPdfRendererNative and RenderPageToSurface, but there isn't a way to override the foreground at that level.

Once you've rendered the page into an off-screen bitmap you can edit its pixels. For example, you can load it into a WriteableBitmap and then loop through the pixels and invert the colours:

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///assets/demo.pdf"));
PdfDocument pdfDoc = await PdfDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(file);
PdfPage pdfPage = pdfDoc.GetPage(0);

using (IRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
{
    PdfPageRenderOptions options = new PdfPageRenderOptions();

    await pdfPage.RenderToStreamAsync(stream, options);

    WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap((int)pdfPage.Size.Height, (int)pdfPage.Size.Width);
    await wb.SetSourceAsync(stream);

    using (Stream pixels = wb.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
    {
        pixels.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i++)
        {
            byte subPixel = (byte)pixels.ReadByte();
            // WB pixels are RGBA. Only change RGB, not A
            if ((i + 1) % 4 != 0)
            {
                // write over the same pixel we just read
                pixels.Seek(-1, SeekOrigin.Current);
                // write the modified pixel (inverted colour in this case)
                pixels.WriteByte((byte)(byte.MaxValue - subPixel));
            }
        }
    }
    // Display the page on an Image in our Xaml Visual Tree
    img.Source = wb;
}
```